# Can I Add/Remove my custom settings bundle in my iOS application?

Tags: ios, settings.bundle

I have a custom settings bundle in my application that provide some additional settings options for a user. But i want that options to be available for some particular users only. Is there is any option to allow/enable my custom app settings for some users only(Programmatically) ?

The flow should be like this:

1. If the user is a regular user (Who does not meet some conditions) , and if he opens the iPhone settings page, my app's custom settings should not be visible for him.
2. If the user is a special user (Who meets my conditions), and if he opens the iPhone settings page,  my app's custom settings should be visible for him.

NB : User has the privilege to meet my conditions during the run time of my application. So the conditions may change during the app running time.

Answer (score 2):

Impossible.

Settings bundle is a part of your app. It is read-only and same for all users.

You need to implement your custom Settings inside your app.